# Using same entity in two models

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am making an library which will be used to talk with database using Entity framework. For different workflows I need different tables from database. So I decided to have separate models for separate workflows. But for some workflows one entity is used in multiple models. Now for one model I have modified my entity class (changed some getters/setters and added custom functions). But when I create new model for different workflow then model will generate entity with default names. I have to edit it again and code will be duplicated. Both are in different namespaces (one is Model1Namespace, second is Model2Namespace).

So what I exactly need is that if entity is used in different classes a single code is used (no duplicate code). What are the best practices? Do EF provide us something or we need to implement it ourself?

Example:

```
Database tables: TableA, TableB, TableC, TableD
Models: Model1 -> TableA, TableB
        Model2 -> TableA, TableC,
        Model3 -> TableC, TableD
```

**Edit:**
I have a database containing 4 tables (TableA, TableB, TableC, TableD). I create a Entity data model of the database which contains TableA and TableB. In entity designer view I modified names of properties of TableA Entity so that they are readable. Now I create another model which contains TableA and TableC. Now here I have to rename all properties of TableA again. Now this is repeat work. Now if I add some custom action to my Entity for Model1 then I have to write (copy) them to new Model2 Entity as well. I need to avoid this. As I really don't know how many models I will create. And if I have to do this stuff again and again then it will take lot of time.

Comment: No way to avoid this. You can however derive both classes from a base class that should not be part of either model.

Comment: What about changing properties name of entities? They are mapped to database columns. I have to do that again and again for every model in which that entity is present. Any workaround?

Comment: Only when you switch to code first. Then you can create contexts and pick the POCOs you want it to map to database tables.

Comment: I am using Database first approach. I have 500+ tables in my database. I cannot apply code first approach.